# To use or not to use inverse geocoding to index a MySQL table with ~500,000 rows?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, geolocation, geocoding

I have a table with about 5,000 rows that contain geocoordinates (latitude+longitude) and location info (city, state and country) on landmarks. I use this table to retrieve the closest locations to a user's position (e.g. nearby parks, etc.).

As for now, I am filtering the query by reverse coding the user's gps coordinates to get his city, state and country (I'm using Android's Geocoder). However, I've come to realize that the Geocoder fails once in a while, therefore the SQL query on my cloud server doesn't return any results.

So I'm thinking in just skipping the reverse coding to be sure to get good results each time. I'll just use the geocordinates to get what I want, like this:

```
SELECT p.placeId, p.name,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( p.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( p.longitude ) - radians($user_longitude) ) + sin( radians($user_latitude) ) * sin( radians( p.latitude  ) ) ) ) AS distance ORDER BY distance
```

However, my table is increasing size each day and might grow up to 500,000 eventually. Do you think that performing the distance calculation on each row might become a performance issue when my table scales to that size? Or is a table of 500,000 rows not really a problem?

Comment: if it ever becomes an issue you could limit the query with a WHERE clause that selects only records that are within (Lat-X,Lon-X):(Lat+X,Lon+X) where X is some rough predetermined value of how far would you like to search in the first place. For example it wouldn't make much sense to calc and order by distance gas stations in Florida when you're in California

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit your search to a radius and number of records you require. In this case 25kms and 20 records.

```
SELECT  placeId, name, lat, lng,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($user_latitude) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians($user_longitude)) + sin( radians($user_latitude))
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM myTable HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

This query took 2.08 secs to run on a 500,000 row MySQL database.

It would be a advisable to use [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) with prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a spatial index. Mssql for example uses a space filling curve. The curve reduces the dimension doesn't cross itself and preserve some original locality informations. The curve is often use in mapping application. Read about it at nick's spatial quadtree hilbert curve blog. I have a written a hilbert curve search for lat lng pairs and it's extremely fast. Instead of a number to index a location you can use a string with 4 letters. Then you can search for the location in the string from left-to-right.  Of course you can reverse the index to lat-lng and back.